# R Get values from multiple other data.frames depending on condition

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, merge, conditional-statements

I have a data.frame `ids` with an index column of person ID number.

```
ID
PA1
PA2
PA3
PA4 
PA5 etc
```

I want to extract the age and sex of each person from 2 other data.frames, `df1` and `df2`which have the details (with different headers), each contains only part of the total sample population, though there maybe some overlap, but also `ids` contains more rows than both `df1` and `df2` combines:

`df1`

```
ID  Sex  Age  Mode
PA1  M   34   HD
PA3  F   45   PD
```

and `df2`

```
ID  Gender  Age   
PA4  M      67
PA3  F      45
PA2  M      65
```

In total there are about 1700 rows of data. I want to get the `Sex` or `Gender` and `Age` from `df1` and `df2` and put them with the correct `ID` in new columns in `ids` data.frame, so I get this:

```
ID   Age   Sex
PA1  34    M
PA2  65    M
PA3 etc...
PA4 
PA5
```

`df1` and `df2` both contain other columns of data which I don't need in `ids` so I don't think I want to use left_join or merge.
I was considering doing something like this with `dlplyr`:

```
ids = ids%>%
   mutate("Sex" = case_when(df1$Gender != "" ~df1$Gender, TRUE ~"" ))
```

and if blank to look in `df2`
but realise that won't match the values with the correct IDs. The IDs are not currently in the same order in the different data.frames

Comment: Could I use an `apply` or `if` statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `left_join` and then just `select` the columns that you need :

```
library(dplyr)

ids %>%
  left_join(df1 ,by = 'ID') %>%
  left_join(df2, by = 'ID') %>%
  select(ID, Age, Sex)
```

---

If there are lot of common columns which are resulting in `.x`, `.y` column after joining you can `select` relevant columns first and then do the join.

```
ids %>%
  left_join(df1 %>% select(Age, Mode), by = 'ID') %>%
  left_join(df2 %>% select(Sex), by = 'ID')
```

Comment: When I do that I end up with two Age coulmns and 2 Sex coulmns: `Age.x` and  `Age.y` and `Sex.x` and `Sex.y`. I guess this is because some of the IDs are common to both df1 and df2

Comment: I think that is because you have `Age` and `Sex` columns in both `df1` and `df2` ? Maybe you need to add one of them in `select` , `Age.x` or add them in `by` i.e `by = c('ID', 'Sex', 'Age')` ?

Comment: Thanks. But I need the Sex and Age data from both `df1` and `df2` because they have different IDs, though some overlap.

Comment: Could I do left join for one df, and a `for` statement to fill in the gaps?

Comment: Do you need a `full_join` then so that all the ids are present in the final dataframe? Would it be possible to create a small reproducible example with `ids`, `df1`, and `df2` and show expected output for it so that it is clear what you want to do.